# How do I seed a foreign key one-to-many list relation?

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, ef-code-first, .net-5

I have class/table:

```
public class Song
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FK_SongTags")]
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Where class/table Tag is:

```
[Table("Tags")]
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my Context I call this seed:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Song>().HasData(new List<Song>
{
    new Song { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Some random song", Tags = new List<Tag> { "pop", "rock" } }
});
```

When I do **dotnet ef database update**, I get:

> The seed entity for entity type 'Song' cannot be added because it has
> the navigation 'Tags' set. To seed relationships,  add the entity seed
> to 'Tag' and specify the foreign key values {'FK_SongTags'}. Consider
> using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
> involved property values.

**How do I solve this error?**

Answer (score 0):

You need many-to-many relations since one song can have several tags, and each tag can be used for another songs too. Try this:

```
public class Song
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
  
    public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}


[Table("Tags")]
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Song> Songs{ get; set; }
}
```

you will have to make an initial migration to db after making changes.

but if you still think that you need one to many try this

```
[Table("Tags")]
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid SongId {get; set;}
     public virtual Song Song {get; set;}

}
```